# Is there any difference between soul and self?

Tags: scripture, philosophy, atma, self

Sanskrit dictionary say this
[image]

[image]

---

So there is a clear difference between soul and self according to the [dictionary](https://www.learnsanskrit.cc/index.php?mode=0)

**MY QUESTION : Is there a difference between these two thing mentioned in the scriptures**.

Comment: Yes difference exist in words.

Comment: Soul is the basic unit of consciousness without which any body is declared dead, while name, height, race etc., are temporary https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adhyāsa or Maya superimpositions over any bound jeeva's Atman until its body's death or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-realization . Every common animal or human know their temporary body self as Mr. X or Miss Y but spirituality is about immortal Soul/Self realization (the actual cause for body's existence), hence soul and self are same for enlightened beings but not others.

Comment: @ManuKumar can you answer it

Comment: Your are conflating English translations with Sanskrit words. Some translators use different English terms when translating Sanskrit Into English as there is no unversal one to one translation methodology. The use of the word 'Self' (capital S) was first used in the 19th century by Europeans to try and refer to the word Atman or Atma (Brahman) when It identifies Itself in the individual jiva. The 'self' (small s) most often refers to an individual's ego, what you might call your individual waking consciousness. Some translators use both Self and self interchangeably.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda thanks sir, but can you answer it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there is no difference between soul and self. Shiva Sutras verse 1.1 says,

> चैतन्यमात्मा 
> Awareness which has absolute freedom of all knowledge and activity is **the Self or nature of Reality or Atma.**

Clearly here self is considered same as Atma. In Vijnanbhairava Tantra, verse 100, it says,

> **The Same self characterized by consciousness is present in all the bodies**; there is no difference in it anywhere. Therefore a person contemplating on everything as full of that consciousness can conquer transmigratory existence.

Kshemraaja in his commentary for the verse above says,

> Moreover **the aforesaid consciousness is the Atma or nature of the entire universes** consisting of both existent object or non-existent but imagined objects(like a sky flower).